# How to import .js files

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi I am developing phonegap application. If I use console.log in index.html file then it prints, but If I use it in another file it doesn't print. If suppose I import files in index.html file like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>             
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jqm.autoComplete-1.4.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="content" >

        <a href="UI/Equity/test.html" data-role="button" id="myButton">index</a>            

    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Then page display with button and print !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!. But on click of button it shows test.html file which is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>             
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jqm.autoComplete-1.4.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="content" >

        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="myButton">Test</a>           

    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

But here it doesn't print @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ why is it so?

Comment: What is folder hierarchy of both files index.html and test.html?

Comment: index file is in www folder (index file is entry point for application)
test file is in www/UI/Equity folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you have jQuery mobile "pages" across different HTML files, what
>   the framework does is grab the content of the data-role="page" element
>   and it inserts that into the current page's DOM.
>
> Anything not in that data-role="page" element is completely ignored. 
>   What this means, is only the scripts in the head of the first page you
>   hit (in this case index.html) are actually downloaded and
>   run, which is why your script needs to be referenced in all the head
>   of all pages.

Check `PageCreate` event [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

OR

Another option is to force refresh the page so the script in page 2 is executed, you can do this by setting:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="content" >

        <a href="UI/Equity/test.html" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" id="myButton">index</a>            

    </div>
</div>
```

Added data-ajax="false"

Comment: after adding data-ajax="false" it prints. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the relative path for importing the javascript files. You may need to change that to impo

Suppose directory path of Test.html from index.html is something like

```
index.html
UI\Equity\Test.html 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>             
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.mobile/jqm.autoComplete-1.4.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply now in test.html file I had added ../../   before each file but still it doesn't print

Comment: It should have work, Close browser open it again and refresh page with ctrl|+f5, secondly view source from browser and locate the script tags and check the path you have. How to check source http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm

Comment: @ Adil Thank you for suggestions and your time.